# Button is not clickable in a child viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, parent-child

I am trying to make a side menu which reacts to a hamburger icon clicked.

I created another storyboard with a ViewConroller which contains the TableView in it.

I created a ViewController for this storyboard ViewController.

In the First ViewController (which is not a container), I have the following code:

```
var menuVC: UIViewController!
var isExpanded = false

@IBAction func MenuTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    isExpanded = !isExpanded
    showMenuVC(shouldExpand: isExpanded)
}

func showMenuVC(shouldExpand: Bool) {
    if shouldExpand {
        // show menu
        if menuVC == nil {
            print ("ONLY ONCE")
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Menu", bundle: .main)
            menuVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuSB") as! MenuVC
            menuVC.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: view.frame.width, dy: 0)
            menuVC.willMove(toParent: self)
            self.view.insertSubview(menuVC.view, at: 0)
            self.addChild(menuVC)
            menuVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.view.frame.origin.x = 80 - self.view.frame.width
        }, completion: nil)
    } else {
        // hide menu
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.view.frame.origin.x = 0
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The thing is, the TableView is not responding to anything. Not scrolling, not clicking. I also tried a UIButton and it is not clickable.

The problem is, that the first ViewController is active while the MenuVC is not.

It is important to have both of them active, since the hamburger icon in the first ViewController closes the menu, but I need the MenuVC to be active as well.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Use the View debugger. Look for a view outside it’s superview. A view outside its superview cannot be touched.

Comment: @matt I already know it is outside the superview. How to solve this? What am I missing?

Comment: Well don’t do that. Once a view is outside its superview, it and all its subviews are untouchable. It’s an incoherent view hierarchy.

Comment: If you don't bother using a third party library, take a look at [SideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this line:

```
self.view.insertSubview(menuVC.view, at: 0)
```

with this:

```
self.view.addSubview(menuVC.view)
```

since I have no idea about the subviews you have in `self.view`, because there might be some views on top of your menu which have `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to `true`